# change the color of images using renderTarget

Tags: xna, monogame, rendertarget

I try to draw an image on the screen with render target. 
I used this code:

```
 _renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(
                 this._graphicsDevice,
                 this._graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
                 this._graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
                 false,
                 this._graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat,
                 DepthFormat.None, 0, RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);

  _graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_renderTarget);
                _spriteBatch.Begin();

   _spriteBatch.Draw(texture, drawPoint, null, Color.Red, 0.0f
                , new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), 0.5f, SpriteEffects.None, 0                         .0f);
                _spriteBatch.End();
      _graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

But, the result image is always black! 
Could you help me to change the color of this image. 
Thanks.

Comment: Note that you are rendering to that texture (_renderTarget), but that is not actually being presented on the screen as it is not being rendered to the backbuffer.  You are essentially drawing your sprite on a texture that simply has the same properties as the backbuffer.  Try setting your render target to null, and don't use _render target.  Do you see anything then?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Render to the screen or render to a texture? And if you are rendering to a texture what do you want to do with it after its ready? If you can answer those you may realise what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? There are several comments and even an answer, and you haven't said anything...

Answer (score 0):

From the code shown, `_spriteBatch.Draw` is only rendering content to `_renderTarget`.

Next you need to render the resulting `RenderTarget2D` to your screen so you can see it.

You already have `_graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null)` in place.  You then just need to make a separate `SpriteBatch.Draw` call passing in your `_renderTarget`.

You can do this because [RenderTarget2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.RenderTarget2D.aspx) extends Texture2D.